# A set is nowhere dense iff its closure is nowhere dense

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that a set, $A$, is nowhere dense, *iff* its closure, $A'$, is nowhere dense. Is the following correct?

First, suppose that $A$ is nowhere dense. Then $A$ intersects no non-empty open sets. So $A'$ is empty. So $(A')'$ (the closure of $A'$) is also empty (in particular, it has empty interior). So $A'$ is nowhere dense.

Second, suppose that $A'$ is nowhere dense. Then $A'$ intersects no non-empty open sets. So $A'$ must be empty (in particular, it has empty interior). So $A$ is nowhere dense.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your definition of being nowhere dense? The proof depends on your definition.

Comment: @HanulJeon  A set is nowhere dense iff it does not intersect any non-empty open sets. A sufficient condition for this is that a sets closure has empty interior.

Comment: @Charles That can't be the definition.  Pick any point in the nonempty set, any open neighbourhood of that point and you have a nonempty intersection.

Comment: @Charles that definition only makes sense when $A$ is open and we require that it wont intersect any **other** open set

Comment: @user10354138 what is the correct approach? Thanks.

Comment: You should find the **correct definition** of nowhere dense subsets first.

Comment: @HanulJeon A set W is nowhere dense if its closure has empty interior.

Comment: Then your problem is quite trivial because the closure of the closure is the closure itself.